# versions-maven-plugin - doesn't build with updated properties.

Tags: maven

I have a `pom.xml` that has this property, for my project `my.project`.

```
    <properties> 
        <my.dependency.version>0.0.10</my.dependency.version> 
    </properties>
```

This version number represents the latest released version of another depenency I'm working on.

While I'm adding new changes to `my.dependency` I'll be building it and installing it to my local repository with version `0.0.11-SNAPSHOT`.

I'll then need to rebuild `my.project` pointing to that dependency - ie. updating `my.dependency.version` to `0.0.11-SNAPSHOT`.

I've tried doing this with the `versions-maven-plugin` as follows:

```
    <profile>
        <id>use-latest</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>

                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>update-dependency-versions</id>
                            <phase>initialize</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>update-property</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <allowSnapshots>true</allowSnapshots>
                                <property>my.dependency.version</property>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>

                      <!--  <execution>
                            <id>clean-up</id>
                            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>revert</goal>
                                 <goal>commit</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution> --> 
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

(I've commented out the clean up for now - more later).

This will modify the pom and update the property to `0.0.11-SNAPSHOT`. However, when it builds the and packages the project, it still uses the old dependency.

If I run it again, it will use the new dependency. This suggests to me that maven reading all the properties before it alters them.

Is there a way I can modify the dependency, and have that dependency then be used in the build and packaging?

Note on clean up: I then want to remove the changes I made, because I don't want the change to be seen by version control.

Comment: apparently a cache of depencencies in the maven reactor. Invoking versions plugin probably activated it, and will not invalidate it, so stuck there for the next plugin in the cycle. Try running it stand-alone first.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The [versions-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/update-property-mojo.html) has the goal `update-property`, which is only meant to be called stand-alone.

If you want to call it before the build, just use `versions:update-property package` instead of `package`

Comment: It seems the versions plugin is not designed to work this way. It makes changes to the POM, but only at the very end of the Maven execution. We had to configure our build to run Maven twice, once with a clean and versions plugin invocation, and then the actual build. As such, we also needed to make the POM file writable.